# Naming methods a, b, c, etc

Tags: java

Lots of times I see people naming their methods a(), b(), c(), etc. instead of giving them names that describe what the method actually does. What is the point of this?

Comment: In what context do you see this happening? I wouldn't expect to see methods that poorly named in production code, certainly where I work that'd immediately fail a code review.

Comment: What people? In what situation?

Comment: I've seen it done in plugins for the game "Minecraft". I think Minecraft itself also names their classes and methods like that.

Comment: In that case this is probably done by some automated program. The code the developer is actually working on probably wouldn't be using these names.

Comment: @Garrett Cause it's harder for dev to read the code. Minecraft's dev certainly used refactoring tools to "obfuscate" their production code so that it's hard to understand how it works.

Comment: Saves wear and tear on the keyboard??  Sadistic desire to torture people trying to read their code??

Answer (score 2):

They shouldn't be doing this. It's bad practice.

Either the developer is being lazy, or they are showing a very simple example(still bad practice).

EDIT: (Given the extra detail in your comments)

In that case this is probably done by some automated program. The code the developer is actually working on wouldn't be using these names.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you were reading obfuscated code.

[Here's a nice article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software))

Comment: Obfuscated code would be much more difficult to read than a, b or c

Comment: Much more likely the developer was just being lazy

Comment: Of course there are varying degrees of obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

To minimize the load time for .js files, many developers will "compress" them.  Compressing also has an option to obfuscate the code, making it more difficult to steal and change by making it difficult to understand.  This happens just as you describe, by changing the variable names and function names to "a", "b", "c", etc.  This has the side-effect of making the code smaller, since the names are now shorter. An example of a web tool that does this for you is here:  http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/compressjavascript/

The code base that you maintain is certainly NOT the one that has been compressed and/or obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. They are just too lazy to follow the standard naming conventions maybe because they are simply doing some quick POC(proof of concept) and they don't want to waste their time in typing some meaningful method name.
But one must always follow the naming conventions in their actual projects where others might be looking/maintaining their code.

Answer (score 0):

**This has always been discouraged by every community into programming and probably is a sign of a bad developer.**

For more information on why and how do we use coding conventions see [this](http://www.iwombat.com/standards/JavaStyleGuide.html)